# Which of three ways to use to update Immutable React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I'm using Immutable JS and React. I was wondering if there is much of a difference in these three methods of updating a state store under then personal stylistic choices:

```
// Method 1
this.setState(({data}) => ({
  data: data.update('count', v => v + 1)
}));

// Method 2
this.setState(prevState => ({
  data: prevState.data.update('count', v => v + 1)
}));

// Method 3
this.setState({ 
  data: this.state.data.update('count', v => v + 1)
});
```

Method 1 seems to use destructuring with the previous state, and Method 2 is similar except it opts out of destructuring. Method 3 is the most divergent in that it references the current state instead of the previous state, but it still seems to work. (will it always?)

Personally I kinda prefer method 3 since it's the least amount code, but I saw the [existing Facebook example](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/wiki/Immutable-as-React-state) use method 1. Does it make much of a difference?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between 1 and 2 is that in 1, you destructure the state into variables. #3 changes how you access the existing state (this.state vs passed to the function). Option 1 has to be compiled or polyfilled, but is cleaner looking code than option 2. There will be no noticible performance difference between any of the 3 options, but #3 is probably minisculely faster since it's just passing the object to update instead of running a function that passes the object to update. The benefit of 1 & 2 is if you wanted to pass functions from somewhere else, you could